# Issue setting up the gradle plugin for Facebook screenshot-tests-for-android

Tags: android, android-testing

I need to implement screenshot testing for android.

I've followed the steps on https://facebook.github.io/screenshot-tests-for-android/#gradle-setup and have the following in my gradle file

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
      // ...
      classpath 'com.facebook.testing.screenshot:plugin:0.9.0'
    }
  }

  apply plugin: 'com.facebook.testing.screenshot'
```

However, I get an error

> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'app-android'.
>   Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.facebook.testing.screenshot']
>   Configuration with name 'androidTestImplementation' not found.

I have the following in my build.gradle

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex-instrumentation:2.0.0'
```

I can't find any evidence that I need anything else.

I've also seen on https://github.com/facebook/screenshot-tests-for-android that

> You need python-2.7 for the gradle plugin to work, and we also recommending installing the python-pillow library which is required for recording and verifying screenshots.

And I've installed that and see that I have version 2.7.16
I've also installed pillow as reccommended (v6.0.0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you may need to move this line:

```
apply plugin: "com.facebook.testing.screenshot"
```

into the module level `build.gradle`. it has to be below this one line:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
```

because that's where the `androidTestImplementation` comes from.

Comment: its better if you put yout classpath to add the plugin into the project gradle file and the the apply plugin into your individual modules

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear in the docs

The line:

```
classpath 'com.facebook.testing.screenshot:plugin:0.14.0'
```

Goes in the project's gradle file (build.gradle .)

And the line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.facebook.testing.screenshot'
```

Goes in your app's gradle file (build.gradle app)